# Removing duplicates and printing different integer pairs that result in the same product

Tags: java

I have been trying to code a program where the user has to input some integers in an array, without duplicates (e.g. having two 3's), and then the program finds pairs of integers that result in the same product within the given array. Moreover, the program cannot display two equal pairs (e.g. 40x1 and 1x40). This is what I have managed to do so far, not sure if it is memory efficient.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] list = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Input the numbers to check if there are any common products");

        for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
            list[k] = sc.nextInt();    
        }       
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
        showProducts(list, 10);
    }   

    static void showProducts(int[] list, int product) {
        Set<Integer> hset = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int pairedNum = 0;
        for (int element : list) {
            if (product % element == 0) {
                hset.add(element);
            }
        }

        for(Integer element : hset) {
            pairedNum = product / element;
            if(hset.contains(pairedNum)) {
                System.out.println(element + pairedNum);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Moreover, the program cannot display two equal pairs (e.g. 40x1 and
>   1x40).

Well, but it does. You could just check for element <= pairedNum (or the other way round, but just one way) to avoid it.

On the other hand: If you make the product flexible,

```
showProducts (list, sc.nextInt ());
```

and the user (or whoever) chooses a square root (like 9) and a single 3 is in the input (and duplicates where eliminated by the set) - should it print/count as a solution?

Printing only if element < pairedNum (or >) would solve that issue.

Else, it is a pretty fast and efficient solution. But it would be a bit faster and meanwhile solve the problem of symmetric pairs, if you would test for the pairedNum immediately while inserting the factor:

```
static void showProducts(int[] list, int product) {
    Set<Integer> hset = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int pairedNum = 0;
    for (int element : list) {
        if (product % element == 0) {
            pairedNum = product / element;
            if (hset.contains (pairedNum)) {
                System.out.println (element + "*" + pairedNum);
            }
            hset.add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that you have to split the output, for example like `System.out.println (element + "*" + pairedNum);` - else the ints get added and then printed (19, 46).

```
echo 12 4 8 5 2 11 16 20 34 44 88 | java Question1 
Input the numbers to check if there are any common products
[12, 4, 8, 5, 2, 11, 16, 20, 34, 44]
11*8
44*2
```

Comment: Many thanks as it works! However, is there a way which I can prevent the user from inputting two equal integers? Such as the following: [12, 4, 8, 4, 2, 8, 1, 12, 2]. I would like to prevent the user from doing such a thing, if possible. Thank you

Comment: No, or nearly no. You can't say, whether he will input 41 when he hit's the 4 button, so you will accept the first cipher 4 and can only check after he inputs (hit enter, leaves an input field) whether the value is valid. You can transform the values soon into the set and early react, for example by loop until he inputted 10 values or you can change the semantic level where you threat the problem and fill the values with random values. In Swing/FX you could present him 10x10 Buttons with values from 2 to 102 where 10 checkboxes have to be marked, before the confirm button is activated.

Comment: Oh then I cannot apply a method where it removes the duplicates or something similar? Thanks for your support

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking. Yes, you can check for duplicates, remove them and ask to fill the collection up.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you need to first change the way you print your pairs since you are adding the `element + pairedNum` before it is transformed into a string to be printed.

The second thing is that you need to remove the quotient once is used, since it cannot be used again. The thing is that you cannot do that while iterating using the `for (value : values)`, you do that using the java iterator.

Modify the second for in the `showProducts` method:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = hset.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    int element = it.next(), pairedNum = product / element;
    if(hset.contains(pairedNum)) {
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(String.format("{%s, %s}", element, pairedNum));
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `Iterator` you can use, you can use another set and add the used elements (`product / element`) in it and then check the first contains is `true` and the second `false`.

You can also use an ordered set `TreeSet` and use the current `contains()` and also if `element < (product / element)`, which would be `true` when element is less than the searched number and it hasn't been used.

For this input `{1, 2, 10, 1, 5, 99, 100, 101, 59, 89}` and `product=10` it will print `{1, 10}` and `{2, 5}`.

Comment: I have done that, however, as I am not so experienced with sets in general, it still gave me an error when I ran it.
Code:

Comment: for(Integer element : hset) {
            Iterator<Integer> it = hset.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                 element = it.next();
                         pairedNum = product / element;
                if(hset.contains(pairedNum)) {
                    it.remove();
                    System.out.println(String.format("{%s, %s}", element, pairedNum));
                }
            }

        }